# Flutter Provider SplashScreen

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

Need a provider to build a splash screen? If yes, Then How to build and call a splash screen in flutter using provider state management?

Comment: 1. Create a splash screen 2. create splash screen provider with changeNotifier and routing with new screen(like your home screen) 3. splash screen route from main.dart

Comment: How do we call that splash screen provider at the beginning of the application(from main.dart)

Comment: Initial route/ home screen would be your splash screen

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I fully understand your problem here.
The goal of a Splashscreen is to load the largest resources of an app to store it on the device or in the RAM, allowing the user to navigate through the app flawlessly.

You shouldn't need a Provider dedicated to a Splashscreen, but you could query APIs and services on the Splashscreen thanks to the Providers